# why is prepared statement not working for creating tables?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code. It is giving a syntax error.

```
$email = $email."_account";
$stat1 = $conn->prepare("create table ?(acc varchar(50) NOT NULL)");

echo mysqli_error($conn);

$stat1->bind_param("s",$email);
$b = $stat1->execute();
```

This is the error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?(acc varchar(50) NOT NULL)'

Also I would like to ask if I should prepare seperate tables for every user. For example if I am preparing a budget manager software then I need accounts for that. So should I store accounts for every user in same table or create seperate tables for every user?

Comment: You should store all you're accounts in one table and don't make a new table for each user. Make a new row for each user

Comment: 1) You can't bind table name to param 2) One way is to concatenate SQL string but it could lead to SQL Injection 3) Table per user indicates poor design

Comment: okay thank you guys lad2025 and Sander